# Java KeyListener for class not extending jpanel or something

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, keylistener

I'm trying to make a KeyListener in a new data type called `Player` which implements KeyListner. How could I make `Player` its own KeyListener (i.e. `this.addKeyListner(this)`) without implementing or extending anything further? If this is not posssible, what would I want `Player` to extend/implement to avoid extraneous methods in the class?

Edit: To clarify, I'm not asking how to implement a KeyListener without the the keyReleased, keyPressed, and keyTyped methods. I'm asking how I can make Player add itself as a KeyListener without it being a JPanel, for example.

Comment: What extraneous methods?  `keyPressed(KeyEvent)` `KeyReleased(KeyEvent e)` `keyTyped(KeyEvent e)` They're all relevant in some way, or don't need anything if not...

Comment: If `Player` implements KeyListener, necessarily must implement the methods that RossC says.

Comment: Unless it's `abstract`.

Comment: I edited the post to address the confusion.

Comment: What's the exact purpose? What is supposed to happen to the player or the program when the key is typed? And pleeeeaaase don't say this is for a console program ;-)

Comment: @peeskillet I can't imagine why that would matter. For now, let's just say that it prints "Hello" to the console on a keyPressed event.

Comment: @peeskillet in reality, it will do a lot of things with other custom data types I have created. Again, can't see the significance to my question.

Comment: Actually, see [What is an X/Y Problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). That's why I asked. Don't be so defensive

Comment: @peeskillet don't mean to be defensive. Just wanted to get to the point of the question.

Comment: The point of the question is to figure out exactly what you trying to accomplish. KeyEvents are used with GUI Programs. So say you have a Player in a console program, And you type a key. Nothing will happen. That's why I asked again, What are you trying to accomplish

Answer (score 1):

If you implement KeyListener (assuming there is no instance of `Abstract`), then you must implement the 3 methods. They are not extraneous for the interface, as these are the 3 things that can happen to a key, they may not all be relevant to you but it's only a couple of lines of code to implement them.

```
void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
```

Invoked when a key has been pressed.

```
void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
```

Invoked when a key has been released.

```
void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
```

Invoked when a key has been typed.

There's only the 3 and this is the nature of interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

### Steps:

- Create a class which extends JPanel, say MyJPanel.
- The JPanel class should provide methods to modify it's attributes.
- Create a separate class which implements KeyListener, say Player.
- Add an object of Player to the JPanel class.
- Call the JPanel methods from the Player class on key events, and then repaint.

### Code:

### The Panel class:

```
public class MyJPanel extends JPanel {

    private int x = 0;
    private int y = 0;

    public MyJPanel() {
        addKeyListener(new Player(this));
        setFocusable(true);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.fillRect(x, y, 100, 100);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyJPanel player = new MyJPanel();
        player.setSize(200, 200);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(player);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setTitle("Key listener example");
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

    void incrementX() {
        x++;
        if (x > 500)
            x = 500;
    }

    void decrementX() {
        x--;
        if (x < 0)
            x = 0;
    }

    void incrementY() {
        y++;
        if (y > 500)
            y = 500;
    }

    void decrementY() {
        y--;
        if (y < 0)
            y = 0;
    }
}
```

### The Player class which implements KeyListener

```
public class Player implements KeyListener {
    MyJPanel panel;

    public Player(MyJPanel myJPanel) {
        this.panel = myJPanel;
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent pKeyEvent) {
        int key = pKeyEvent.getKeyCode();
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            panel.decrementX();
        } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            panel.incrementX();
        } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            panel.decrementY();
        } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            panel.incrementY();

        }
        panel.repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent pKeyEvent) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent pKeyEvent) {
    }
}
```